# Does the order in which reputation is earned influence your daily limit?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

While [studying how reputation is earning](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) I came across seemingly contradictory assertions:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day **from any combination** of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses **are not subject** to the daily reputation limit.

Emphasis mine. I already know from experience that if I earned +200 points in a day, I can still earn an extra +100 points by associating a new Stack Exchange account.

My question, however, is what happens in reverse? If I started with 0 points and then associate two accounts, for example, would I still earn points on upvotes in that day? Are bounty points, association points, and completely agnostic of the daily maximum? If so, why are they in the list of "activities" from which "any combination" will be limited to the daily maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation-gaining activities that don't count towards the daily max don't affect your ability to gain reputation from upvotes in any way. The help center article is just awkwardly phrased... I'm open to suggestions for a clearer explanation, since one's not coming to me at the moment.

> If I started with 0 points and then associate two accounts, for example, would I still earn points on upvotes in that day?

You only gain the association bonus once per network account, so associating two profiles wouldn't give you 200 reputation on any one site.

Comment: This suggests that there is an order dependence if downvotes are involved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Oh yeah, that's true. I was only talking about events that don't count towards the cap to begin with.

Comment: This one also suggests that the order of upvotes and accepts matters: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/only-apply-the-rep-cap-to-score-from-votes. But it's old. Is this still true?

Comment: @RetoKoradi It's marked completed, so I'm going to assume it's fixed/implemented. Not sure off the top of my head, though.